# How to remove sql character limit when converting from varbinary to base64?

Tags: sql-server, base64, varbinary

I want to convert a image from varbinary to base64. At current, I've found that my base64 output is being cut short. Is there anyway or any tools that would give me my full base64 string?

When I run my script in sql server managment studio I get 43,679 characters which gives me half my image when I convert back to an image. When I run in sql operations studio I get 65,536, which gives me 3/4 of my image when I convert my base64 to an image.

```
 SELECT 
     COALESCE((SELECT CAST('' AS xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("d.DocumentData"))', 'nvarchar(max)')), '')
 FROM 
     Documents d
 WHERE 
    d.Document = 43
```

Comment: I assume you're copying this data from SSMS. If so, this'll likely be your Maximum Characters Retrieved setting (Tools > Options > Query Resuts > SQL Server > Results to Grid), which has a maximum value of 65535 for Non XML data. The data will still be stored fine, you just can't copy more than that many characters out of the application. I've no idea what your trying to do with the data, but if you're reading the data with an application, then it'll see the full value; it's just when you literally copy the value out of SSMS. I assume ADS has a similar setting/"feature".

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for your response. I want to convert my images to base64 before my API picks up the images as this has been causing me significant performance issues due to it converting to base64 and then uploading together. As long as my api can read the output of my script that's all i'm concerned with. It's just odd that SOS can have more characters. I've tried outputting to both a file and text but still the result is cut short.

Comment: SSMS can do up to 65535 as well, but i don't believe that's the default setting. If you check the setting I've provided I'd suggest it'll display 43679. *P.s. it's not called SOS anymore, it's ADS now (Azure Data Studio). They changed the name at launch for some reason. If you are still using SOS, you're using the CTP/RC release, so I'd suggest updating to the RTM version.*